# Does sharing laptop Wi-Fi cause network noises or network slow down?

Tags: networking, ieee-802.11, network-access

We have network (Wifi network) issues in our organization the network is slow and sometimes the access point throw out some connected users. We contacted ISP and they checked our network configuration and it all good they said. But they state that many of these issues are because of wifi sharing through `Mars Wifi`.

Does using `Mars Wifi` or `Virtual Router` really causes such issues?

Comment: Mars Wi-Fi and virtual routers are off-topic here because the manufacturer does not offer optional paid support. Also, it sounds like you are using a consumer-grade router supplied by your ISP. Your company needs to spend some money an take control of your network with real business equipment and some expertise from within or through and expert consultant.

Answer (score 2):

Mars WIFI sounds like a completely terrible idea in general. For an emergency setup for an hour or two while you don't have any other option, it is probably fine, but certainly not for long term or permanent use.
As others have said, the proper solution is to employ someone who has experience with business or enterprise networks to look at your needs on site and help you solve your issues with reliable and appropriate equipment upgrades.

Comment: I don't think that Wifi sharing is their intend - it's just what their employees do because they're not stopped. And it's causing the WLAN to fail.

Comment: Very possible that is correct. If employees are installing network sharing software on company computers, the need to be stopped via company policy enforcement, and via technical restrictions. Allowing employees to use company resources like that is a big danger to security.

Answer (score 0):

Heavy use of wireless networks can definitely cause slowdowns, up to the point of failure/denial of service. The WAPs or your NAT router may simply get overloaded.

[edit] I understand your question so that the employees are sharing the Internet with the outside and install software without authorization. [/edit]

First, you'd need to establish a reasonable usage policy for your network - what users may do and what they definitely mustn't do. Then you can configure or upgrade your network to enforce that policy.

Since we know nothing about your network and product recommendations are explicitly off topic here, we can't provide much help with the upgrade unfortunately. If you add the relevant information to your question (a network diagram and the device types/models) we might be able to give you some starting points though. Note that consumer-grade devices are explicitly off topic here, however.

It might also be a good idea to hire a seasoned (and independent) consultant at this point.